# Game fps shutting down

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I created View Controller for Game Over Scene. fps is shutting down when I restart game from Game Over ViewController. First time my fps is 30+, when I restart game it shutting down to 20, and I restart again it shutting down to 10...
and sometimes i see this error : Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for GameOverViewController: 0x9bb8490>.

```
ViewController.m

- (void)awakeFromNib {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(goToGameOverViewController:)
 name:@"GoToGameOverViewController"
 object:nil];
}

-(void)goToGameOverViewController:(NSNotification *) notification {
GameOverViewController *gameOverController = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameOverViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameOverController animated:NO];
 }
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MyScene.m


- (void)gameOver {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"GoToGameOverViewController" object:self];
}
```

---

```
GameOverView.m


-(void)playPressed
{
GameViewController *gameController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameController animated:YES];
}

-(void)createPlayButton
{
UIButton *playBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.view addSubview:playBtn];

playBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 44);
[playBtn setTitle:@"Play Again" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playBtn sizeToFit];
[playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playPressed)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple core issues you have with your code and approach:

1. You continually push `UIViewController`s onto your `UINavigationController`. Instead, maybe after a game finishes, you call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` or other. Every `UIViewController` you push on the stack stays around forever.
2. You never remove observers from `NSNotificationCenter`. That means each time you finish a level, each viewController is trying to push a GameOver viewController. That is what is causing the "unbalanced..." warnings. If you follow my advice from #1, you should only need to override dealloc and call the following code to fix that issue.

In `playPressed` use this code:

```
GameViewController *gameController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameViewController"];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[gameController] animated:YES];
```

And in later in `GameViewController`

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
}
```

This will make sure your ViewController, and therefore your scene, get deallocated and you don't have multiple ViewController trying to push games at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you free your `SKScene` when leaving from `ViewController`:

```
-(void)goToGameOverViewController:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [((SKView *)self.view) presentScene:nil];

    GameOverViewController *gameOverController = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameOverViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gameOverController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I mean, technically this would fix the issue, but it's only a band-aid really. Continually pushing ViewControllers is the real issue.